# Xcode 9 jump to definition doesn't work anymore

Tags: swift, xcode

I have the latest version of Xcode 9 and all of the sudden jump to definition does not work. Every time I select it or use the hot keys for it, Xcode just displays a large ? mark.

Comment: Does Xcode say it's still indexing? Jump to definition won't work if it is since it doesn't know where everything is yet.

If it's not, you can try deleting derived data and relaunching Xcode, which often kicks in the indexing process again.

Comment: delete derived data like so Shift + alt + command ⌘ + K

Comment: It doesn't say anything other than build succeeded and run perfectly on the simulator. I've cleared derived data twice and restarted Xcode each time. No matter what I try I just get a ? mark prompt on my screen. I've tried on my iMac and it works perfectly. Just my MacBook has the issue.

Comment: Your definition may be from another class @Nick B

Comment: It won't even jump to definition on the set functions in Xcode. I've tried it on every item in my services, models, and controllers and still nothing but the ? mark.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to run Xcode and your project as root, coz for me(as for regular user(not root)) jump to definition stop working when i build my proj as root.

to start xcode as root
`>> sudo /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode`